# How do you pass a socket object to a route?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

My goal is = 
user click friends request, then it will sent it to the targeted user.

I have two problems right now

How do I pass in socket object to a router without wrapping the router in the `io.on(‘connection’, function())`?

My current code right now

```
module.exports = function(express, io) {
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/add-friend', function(req, res, next) {
    var userId = req.body.userId;
    console.log(userId);

    User.update(
      {
        _id: userId,
        friendsRequested: { $ne: userId }
      },
      {
        $push: { friendsRequested: { requestee: req.user._id } },
      }, function(err, count) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        io.emit('friendsRequest', req.user); // I want to change io to socket
        res.json("success");
      });

    });

   return router;
}
```

If you take a look at io.emit, my goal is to change that to socket which is

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
   socket.on() // <-- I want to pass it socket to the router
});
```

So that I could do

```
socket.emit('friendsRequest', req.user);
```

In the server.js

```
var routes = require('./routes.js') (express, io);
app.use(routes);
```

How do i pass in socket object without wrapping it out?

The reason why I want to pass in only socket is because I want only the targeted user receive the notification which is friends Request. Any thoughts about this ?

Comment: Unrelated comment to the question, I think you need a `'friendsRequested.requestee': {$ne: userId}` there.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the socket.io is binded to app object and can be accessible from the req object in your route. Then, you can use room to select the specific socket you want to handle. So you could access it just like this

in your app.js:

```
app.io = socket_io();
```

in your router.js

```
router.post('/add-friend', function(req, res, next) {

    //here you can access socket
    var socket = req.app.io.off('/add-friend');

    //or if your socket is in a room (room name could be the user Id)
    var socket = req.app.io.off('/add-friend').to('roomName');

    //or if your socket is connected via '/'
    var socket = req.app.io.off('/').to('roomName');

    var userId = req.body.userId;
    console.log(userId);

    User.update(
      {
        _id: userId,
        friendsRequested: { $ne: userId }
      },
      {
        $push: { friendsRequested: { requestee: req.user._id } },
      }, function(err, count) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        socket.emit('friendsRequest', req.user); // I want to change io to socket
        res.json("success");
      });

    });

   return router;
}
```

Comment: Im confused about socket_io(); do i need to install a library or something?

Comment: Yes, you need to install socket.io on server via npm and include the client version of socket.io in your client html. Both are not the same.

Comment: The one on the server I did installed already  `var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);`

Comment: how do i use socket_io()?

Comment: as you do `var io = require('socket.io');` , you have to do `app.io = io();`

Comment: To be honest i did `app.io = io()` as well, but i keep getting `TypeError: object is not a function`

Comment: Have you installed socket.io using `npm install socket.io --save` ?

Comment: Yeah I did save it to package.json

Comment: You should post all your code. app.js and routes. What version of express are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your socket handlers should be a little diverse and have an API for that.

Socket handler can expose `getSocketByUserId` functionality, or even more specific, a `sendFriendRequest` function directly.

Something like:

```
var sendFriendRequest = require('./socket').sendFriendRequest;
var Promise = require('bluebird');
router.post('/add-friend/:userId', function(req, res, next) {

  // skipping the database stuff for this example
  sendFriendRequest(req.user, req.params.userId)
  .then(function() {
    res.json({message: 'request sent'})
  })
  .catch(next);
});

// And in './socket'
var sockets = {};

io.on('connect', function(socket) {

  // get userId somehow
  sockets[userId] = socket;
  // do other stuff
});
export function sendFriendRequest(requestor, userId) {

  if (sockets[userId]) {
    sockets[userId].emit({ type: 'friendRequest', from: requestor.id, fromUsername: requestor.username});
    Promise.resolve('Request sent.');
  } else {
    Promise.reject(new Error('User not connected.'));
  }
});
```

Of course, I've omitted a lot of boilerplate stuff, but that's one way to do it.

Comment: seems like I couldn't fix the problem with sendFriendRequest, it keeps showing error with `then()`

Comment: Do you use one of the later versions of node? You do have Promise there? What do you catch in that .catch?

Comment: Im using es5 syntax, and the node.js version is 0.12

Comment: are you sure the code that you wrote is correct in the router?

Comment: No, I didn't test it. But it is the gist of it. You don't have to use Promises, you can use a simple callback. Like, `module.exports.sendFriendRequest = function(requestor, userId, callback) { /*do socket emit then: */ callback();`, and in your router: `sendFriendRequest(req.user, userId, function() { /*handle from here on */})`

Comment: im not used to es2015 yet. Can you update your code in the answer thanks in advance

Comment: There, it should be more ES5 now. Even added `bluebird` for Promise action.